# Get all unmatching elements between two large lists

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a `dictionary<string, Foo>` with X amount of elements. The dictionary key is containing `Foo.Id`. I also have a `List<Foo> newFoos`, which in my case contains a little less elements than the dictionary. So what I would like to do, is have a new `List<Foo>` with all the elements that are in `newFoos` but not in my dictionary.

I solved this by using:

```
var list = MyDict.Where(x => newFoos.All(y => y.Id != x.Key)).ToList();
```

But the problem with this was performance in my case, it must be some easier and faster way? And please not by using Except/Intersect and override Equals

```
    public class Program {

    public static Dictionary<int, Foo> MyDict { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, Foo>(); 
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            MyDict.Add(i, new Foo() {Id = i});
        }

        var newFoos = new List<Foo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            newFoos.Add(new Foo() { Id = i });
        }

        var list = MyDict.Where(x => newFoos.All(y => y.Id != x.Key)).ToList();
    }
}

public class Foo  {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    //More properties

}
```

When using my testcode above I find it not that slow, but the principle is the same

Comment: `MyDict` I hate that variable name.

Comment: Improving working code is off-topic and fits better to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TimSchmelter - True lol

Comment: I'd imagine that checking Keys.Contains would produce some kind of speed improvement. At the least it would probably optimize better than checking every key in the dictionary. But Tim's right.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well maybe. But If I just wanna make it faster then?

Comment: Since you don't want Except/Intersect (assuming you don't like hash table approach taken there which is the way to get O(n+m)) you should settle for O(n*m) approach you have. If your list would be sorted you could go with O(n log m) but it does not seem to apply in your case. (n - number of items in dictionary, m - items in list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = newFoos.Where(x => !MyDict.ContainsKey(x.Id)).ToList();
```

This should be more efficient since checking if a key is in a dictionary should be faster than looking up an item in a list.

Comment: This is obvious improvement, but it is unclear if OP is looking for such answer as they already dismissed Except approach which is essentially the same as this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the index access on the list is slightly faster than using an enumerator. As already stated, checking the Key existance also is much faster than accessing each item, this results in a for...ContainsKey...

```
        List<Foo> addedFoos = new List<Foo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < newFoos.Count; i++)
        {
            Foo current = newFoos[i];
            if (MyDict.ContainsKey(current.Id))
            {
                addedFoos.Add(current);
                //MyDict.Add(current.Id, current); /* see remark below */
            }
        }

        //addedFoos.ForEach(item => MyDict.Add(item.Id, item.Value)); /* see remark below */
```

If you intend to add them to the dictionary, depending on the amount of newFoos, it may be better to Add the items after finding them instead of in the loop, because otherwise you will enlarge the Dictionary while searching with items that will never cause a hit anyway.